# How to access JSON decoded array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I returned an array of `JSON` data type from `javascript` to `PHP`, I used `json_decode($data, true)` to convert it to an associative array, but when I try to use it using the associative `index`, I get the error `"Undefined index"` The returned data looks like this

```
array(14) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "597" ["c_name"]=> string(4) "John" ["next_of_kin"]=> string(10) "5874594793" ["seat_no"]=> string(1) "4" } 
[1]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "599" ["c_name"]=> string(6) "George" ["next_of_kin"]=> string(7) "6544539" ["seat_no"]=> string(1) "2" } 
[2]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "601" ["c_name"]=> string(5) "Emeka" ["next_of_kin"]=> string(10) "5457394839" ["seat_no"]=> string(1) "9" } 
[3]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "603" ["c_name"]=> string(8) "Chijioke" ["next_of_kin"]=> string(9) "653487309" ["seat_no"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Please, how do I access such array in `PHP`? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: You access it like any other array because it is just that, an array. It does not matter where it came from. If you get an error, it means that the key you are trying to access does not exist. So, double check that the key you want to access exists. If you are new to arrays in PHP, have a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

Comment: can you add the code where you're trying to access the elements?  (and clean up the array so its easier to read)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As you're passing `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode`, in the above example you can retrieve data doing something similar to:

```
$myArray = json_decode($data, true);
echo $myArray[0]['id']; // Fetches the first ID
echo $myArray[0]['c_name']; // Fetches the first c_name
// ...
echo $myArray[2]['id']; // Fetches the third ID
// etc..
```

If you do NOT pass `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode` it would instead return it as an object:

```
echo $myArray[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data[0]["c_name"]; // "John"


$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data[0]->c_name;      // "John"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = json_decode(...);
$firstId = $data[0]["id"];
$secondSeatNo = $data[1]["seat_no"];
```

Just like this :)

Comment: When I try accessing that way, I get the error " Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".

Comment: Then you're not actually parsing the data as an associative array.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you're passing true as the second parameter to `json_decode`, in the above example you can retrieve data doing something similar to:

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you!

```
$latlng='{"lat":29.5345741,"lng":75.0342196}';
$latlng=json_decode($latlng,TRUE); // array
echo "Lat=".$latlng['lat'];
echo '<br/>';
echo "Lng=".$latlng['lng'];
echo '<br/>';



$latlng2='{"lat":29.5345741,"lng":75.0342196}';
$latlng2=json_decode($latlng2); // object
echo "Lat=".$latlng2->lat;
echo '<br/>';
echo "Lng=".$latlng2->lng;
echo '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to loop into a multiple dimensions array, you can use foreach like this:

```
foreach($data as $users){
   foreach($users as $user){
      echo $user['id'].' '.$user['c_name'].' '.$user['seat_no'].'<br/>';
   }
}
```

Comment: How would I then decode the hourly data from https://api.forecast.io/forecast/... ? I've tried everything but can't get the sub array

Comment: What's the format of the json result? Do you call the service using javascript?