# How to get data from array [API/JSON]

Tags: php, json

I'm currently trying to get going with API's but i'm finding it really hard to extract the data from the api into my webpage.

I have tried using json_decode($, true), and it works OK, but some data I just cant extract.

Like, in this example, how would you get the name?

```
{"id":12345678,"name":"MyAwesomeLeagueName","profileIconId":593,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1389164617000}
```

I have used for getting data from others, but cant really get it to work with types like this one.

```
//put json in array 
$r = json_decode($r, true); 
echo $r['champions'][1]['attackRank'];
```

Also, if anyone have some good JSON -> PHP Tutorials I would really appreciate.

Comment: There are no tutorials. There's nothing to teach. JSON is a string format, which decodes into a PHP data structure. The tutorial would simply be "look at PHP array/object documentation". `var_dump($r)` will tell you everything you need to know. `echo $decoded_stuff['name']` would be all you need.

Comment: I am not really sure about your question at all, but you should be able to just do `$r['name']` because you set `assoc=true` in json_decode.

Comment: you can view this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043981/how-to-access-json-decoded-array-in-php

Comment: Ohh, okay, I see. But, what i I have a lot of data like: http://pastebin.com/A1sQFX50 is there a way I can get like, all with magicrank:8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that example to access the name you just need to refer to $r['name'] e.g.

```
echo $r['name'];
```

After decoding the JSON string, do a var_dump on your array and it will show you the contents and how to access.

To get all with a certain magic rank as per your example, you'd need to loop through the array and test the value of the particular key:

```
$r = json_decode($r, true);

//loop through $r
foreach ($r['champions'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['magicRank'] != 8) {
    //if magicRankis not 8, ignore and move on to the next entry
    continue;
  }
  //magicRank is 8, do something
  echo $value['name'] . " has magic rank of 8<br />";
}
```

Comment: How would I be able to echo them all out? Thanks so far

Comment: See updated answer for a very simple example. This would echo: "<Name> has magic rank 8". By the way, your pastebin example is not valid JSON - you are missing "]}" from the end of the string.

Comment: I know some is missing, I just took a little part, cause the original is SO big. :) So to understand, the $value, is how I "Catch" it in my array? in this example

Comment: json_decode turns the json string into a PHP array. Then you loop with "foreach" - you can choose your own variable names there but I used $key and $value. $key will be the numerical index of each entry in the array. $value will be an array storing all of the details. e.g. $value['name'] will be the name, $value['active'] will have the boolean value of active, etc.

Comment: Thats really cool man, thanks :) Just to ask, do you know if its possible to like, if I get a champion with like id":266, then when i echo, it will do it with a small avatar instead of the name? Just wanna know if its possible :)

Comment: Of course, you'd just do if ($value['id'] == 266) { echo '<img src="images/avatar.png" alt="avatar" />'; } else { echo $value['name']; } or something like that.