# Angular Js call function in ng-selected

Tags: angularjs

I am stuck select box preselected values.

I have student data stored in the database , Subjects data stored in this form:
["23","45","3"]

HTML looks like :

```
<select class="form-control selecBox"   name="classSubject[]" multiple required id="classSubj">
                                <option ng-repeat="subject in form.allsubjects" value="{{subject.id}}" ng-selected="form.classSubject.indexOf(subject.id)>-1">{{subject.subjectTitle}}</option>
                            </select>
```

JS file:

```
$scope.edit = function(id){
        showHideLoad();
        dataFactory.httpRequest('index.php/students/'+id).then(function(data) {

            //console.log("Say No To curruption:"+JSON.stringify(data, null,null));
            //console.dir(data)

            $scope.changeView('edit');
            $scope.form = data;
            //data.classSubject.toString();
            //data.classSubject=data.classSubject.replace("[", "");
            //data.classSubject=data.classSubject.replace("]", "");
            //data.classSubject=data.classSubject.split(",");
            //data.classSubject="16";
            //data.classSubject=data.classSubject.split(",");
            $scope.SelectedSubjects = data.classSubject;//"37";//[37,38,39];//data.classSubject[0];

            console.log(data.classSubject);
            showHideLoad(true);
        });
    }
```

PHP Controller :

```
function fetch($id){
        $data = \User::where('role','student')->where('id',$id)->first()->toArray();
        $data['birthday'] = $this->panelInit->unix_to_date($data['birthday']);
        //$data['classSubject'] =($data['subjects']);
        $data['comVia'] = json_decode($data['comVia'],true);

        $data['classSubject']=json_decode($data['subjects'],true);


        if(!is_array($data['comVia'])){
            $data['comVia'] = array();
        }

        $data['academicYear'] = array();
        $academicYear = \academic_year::get();
        foreach ($academicYear as $value) {
            $data['academicYear'][$value->id] = $value->yearTitle;
        }

        $DashboardController = new DashboardController();
        $data['studentAcademicYears'] = array();
        $academicYear = \student_academic_years::where('studentId',$id)->orderBy('id','ASC')->get();
        foreach ($academicYear as $value) {
            $data['studentAcademicYears'][] = array("id"=>$value->academicYearId,"default"=>$value->classId,"defSection"=>$value->sectionId,"classes"=>\classes::where('classAcademicYear',$value->academicYearId)->get()->toArray(),"classSections"=>$DashboardController->classesList($value->academicYearId) );
        }
         $data['allsubjects']=$subjects=\DB::table('subject')->get();
         //$data['classSubject'] =json_encode($data['allsubjects'][12],true);

        return $data;
    }
enter code here
```

the issue here is: if subject.id=3 then both option "3" and "23" selected  it must select only one option with option value(3)

Comment: could you share the entire select element

Comment: Add more details and code which you already have please

Comment: I added more below in comments with screen shots

Answer (score 0):

use track by $index in your ng-repeat 
$index will uniquely identify the items in array.

Comment: Could you please let me know how  to put here:  <select class="form-control selecBox"   name="classSubject[]" multiple required id="classSubj">
                                <option ng-repeat="subject in form.allsubjects" value="{{subject.id}}" ng-selected="form.classSubject.indexOf(subject.id)>-1">{{subject.subjectTitle}}</option>
                            </select>

Comment: <select class="form-control selecBox" name="classSubject[]" multiple required id="classSubj"> <option ng-repeat="subject in form.allsubjects track by $index" value="{{subject.id}}" ng-selected="form.classSubject.indexOf(subject.id)>-1">{{subject.subjectTitle}}</option> </select>

Comment: when I pass this pre-selected values of Array [ "9", "16" ] from controller  to tempalate file with select box taga , ng-selected="form.classSubject.indexOf(subject.id)>-1 Nothing selected now

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043981/how-to-access-json-decoded-array-in-php

Comment: I solved it myself  by putting pair of brackets    {{form.classSubject.indexOf(subject.id)>-1}}

Answer (score 0):

[Template file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUpKZ.png)

Html file: 
PHP controller

[PHP controller  file image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD8sW.png)

data is in this format: ["23","3"]

[app.js file image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymfja.png)