# How to check the response from the string

Tags: php

I'm getting the response from the api as below :

```
"{"message":"2323232323","type":"errror"}";
```

i want to check the type , i'm unable to retrieve the value of type from the response.

The response is of string i checked using var_dump.

Any idea is most welcome .

Comment: use json_decode and gettype() function.

Comment: $data = '{"message":"2323232323","type":"errror"}'; echo gettype($data['message']);

Comment: share how you are getting this response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is in json format, use json_decode to turn it into a PHP variable and reference the elements as follows:

```
<?php
$json = '{"message":"2323232323","type":"errror"}';

$arr = json_decode($json);

echo "'type' is : ";
echo $arr->type;
echo '<br />';
echo "'message' is : ";
echo $arr->message;
```

Alternatively, json_decode() offers the option to return an associative array by setting the second argument to 'true'. Elements can then be referenced as follows:

```
$json = '{"message":"2323232323","type":"errror"}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

echo "'type' is : ";
echo $arr['type'];
echo '<br />';
echo "'message' is : ";
echo $arr['message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

your have 2 possibilies:

1. you can decode your json by using the json_decode($yourJsonString) function. this will return you an array with the variables inside.

> ```
> $json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';
> $obj = json_decode($json);
> print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345
> ```

2. Please use in future the search of Stackoverflow. The Question is duplicated
   [How to access JSON decoded array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043981/how-to-access-json-decoded-array-in-php)

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you content of `type`.

```
$json = '{"message":"2323232323","type":"errror"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array['type']);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON decodes your string and you will get object and from that you can fetch your value:

```
$res = json_decode('{"message":"2323232323","type":"errror"}');

echo $res->type;
```