# JSON decode multi-level?

Tags: php, json

```
"links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1B56960729604235TKQQIYVY",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-60385559L1062554J",
      "rel": "approval_url",
      "method": "REDIRECT"
    },
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1B56960729604235TKQQIYVY/execute",
      "rel": "execute",
      "method": "POST"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
$responseurl = json_decode($responseurl, true);
echo $responseurl["links"]["href"][0];
```

I have tried multiple combinations such as `$responseurl["links"][0]` but there has been no luck, I am really hoping someone can help me as I am a little stuck!

Many thanks,
John

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access JSON decoded array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043981/how-to-access-json-decoded-array-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

By looking at json provided here, to access `href` from first element in array, it should be like:

```
echo $responseurl["links"][0]["href"];
```

Comment: I can accept the answer in 12 minutes, please remind me!