# How to work with this JSON, including array

Tags: php, json

I tried to work with basic, few param. JSON code and there wasn't any problem with that.

BUT now i need work with this "advanced" JSON and I am kinda lost

```
  {
   "code":"success",
   "username":"x",
   "nodes":[
      {
         "id":"68",
         "time":987
      },
      {
         "id":"69",
         "time":987
      }
   ]
}
```

When i tried to get the values into PHP variable with previou code, I wasn't able to get `ID` and `TIME`, `CODE` and `SUCCESS` isn't problem.

PHP code I used:

```
$url = "example.com";
$url = str_replace(" ","%20",$url);
$json = @file_get_contents($url);
$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);
// print_r($details);
echo $details[code];
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access JSON decoded array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043981/how-to-access-json-decoded-array-in-php)

Comment: `echo $details['nodes'][0]['id'];`

Comment: Thank you! It is working.

May I ask you, how can I count and print out number of total arrays?

"nodes":[
      {
         "id":"68",
         "time":987
      },
      {
         "id":"69",
         "time":987
      }
   ]

in this case i would like to get number 2

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "example.com";
$url = str_replace(" ","%20",$url);
$json = @file_get_contents($url);
$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);
if (is_array($details['nodes'])) {
    echo "node count: " . count($details['nodes']) . "<br />";
    foreach ($details['nodes'] as $node) {
        echo "id: " . $node['id'] . "<br />";
        echo "time: " . $node['time'] . "<br />";
    }
}
```